# If a div contenteditable is focused?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So Basically I have:

HTML:

```
<div class="div1">
  <div class="as-text-box" contenteditable="true"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.div1{
  position:absolute;
  height:50px;
  width:200px;
  background:white;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.as-text-box{
  position:absolute;
  height:30px;
  width:90%;
  background:#ddd;
  top:10px;
  left:5%;
}
[contentEditable=true]:focus .div1{
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

To be precise I need to change the border color of `div1` to black if `as-text-box` is focused.

I also tried it with JQuery but still no luck.

JQuery:

```
$(function(){
    if ($(".as-text-box").is(":focus")) {
        alert("Has Focus");
    } else {
        alert("Doesn't Have Focus");
    }
});
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2xn5rj2y/

All relies are much appreciated.

Comment: You can't navigate up in css selectors

Comment: @LcSalazar What else choice do I have?

Comment: I've posted a JS solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't navigate to a parent element on a css selector. You'll need Javascript for that.

If you want the parent element to change border when the child one is focused, attach a listener to the `blur` and `focus` events of the editable div.

```js
$(".as-text-box").on("focus", function() {
    $(".div1").addClass("focusClass");
});

$(".as-text-box").on("blur", function() {
    $(".div1").removeClass("focusClass");
});
```

```css
.div1{
  position:absolute;
  height:50px;
  width:200px;
  background:white;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.as-text-box{
  position:absolute;
  height:30px;
  width:90%;
  background:#ddd;
  top:10px;
  left:5%;
}

.div1.focusClass {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">
  <div class="as-text-box" contenteditable="true"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector:

```
[contentEditable=true]:focus .div1
```

is trying to select an element with class `div1` which is a descendant of a `contentEditable` element which is focused. This is clearly backwards as the `.div1` div is the parent of the `contentEditable` div.

Simply removing the `.div1` part of the selector makes it work:

```css
.div1{
  position:absolute;
  height:50px;
  width:200px;
  background:white;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.as-text-box{
  position:absolute;
  height:30px;
  width:90%;
  background:#ddd;
  top:10px;
  left:5%;
}
[contentEditable=true]:focus{
 border:1px solid black;
  outline:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="as-text-box" contenteditable="true">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

It would also work to reverse the order if you have other reasons for needing to select on `div1`, but I feel the above solution is the simplest absent other requirements.

Comment: I'm sorry but you misunderstood the question, I need to change the parent of `contenteditable` border color means the `div1` border color to black, not the `contenteditable` border itself.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking to customize the outline css attribute.

CSS

```
outline:none;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2xn5rj2y/5/

If you are trying to target the parent to have a border, then jquery .parent().css("border","1px solid #000"); would work.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do it through css (to select parent), you can do it via jQuery with events `focusin` and `focusout` where you can do with parent element what you want.

```js
$('.as-text-box').on('focusin', function(){
  /** on focus, set border to a parent **/
  $(this).parent().css({'border':'1px solid black'});
}).on('focusout', function(){
  /** on lost focus, remove border **/
  $(this).parent().css({'border':''}); 
});
```

```css
.div1{
  position:absolute;
  height:50px;
  width:200px;
  background:white;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.as-text-box{
  position:absolute;
  height:30px;
  width:90%;
  background:#ddd;
  top:10px;
  left:5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">
  <div class="as-text-box" contenteditable="true">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Short & simple. When it has focus border turns black, if it loses focus it goes back to #ccc.

```
$('.as-text-box').on('focus', function() {
$('.div1').css("borderColor", "black");
$(this).on('focusout', function() {
    $('.div1').css("borderColor", "#ccc");
});
```

});

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kopitar71/2xn5rj2y/21/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=2xn5rj2y)